# Passing *ngFor value in function when creating addEventListener

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating event listener below and I have no idea how to set ngFor value to this.pop for parameter.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.spells img')
                              .addEventListener('mouseover', this.pop.bind(this, event));
}
```

This is HTML code

```
    <ul class= "list-unstyled row">
      <li *ngFor = "let z of data(m[m.length-1]) | slice: 0 : 10; index as j" class = "list-item col-6">
        <img class = "champ" src = {{z[0]}}/>
        <div class = "spells">
          <img src = {{z[1].spellurl}}/>
          <img src = {{z[2].spellurl}}/>
          <div class = "desc"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

So when I mouse over those images in div.spell, I want to call function, pop

```
    pop(event){
    //let ds = document.getElementsByClassName(".spells .desc");
    let pos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let newpos = "translate(" + pos.right + "px, " + pos.bottom + "px)";
    console.log(newpos);
    let selected = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.spells .desc');
    selected.style.display = "block";
    selected.innerHTML = desc;
    selected.style.transform = newpos;
}
```

The function will decide the position of div.desc and its contents. I can use "event" to calculate the position but a problem is `selected.innerHTML` that "z" in `*ngFor = "let z of data(m[m.length-1])` has description which I want to use that as contents of the div but I don't know how to use that value as parameter of the function in addEventListener.

Any suggestion?? thank you

Comment: Why are you manually attaching the events instead of using `(mouseover)="pop($event)"`?

Comment: It seems like you have recently made a transition from jQuery/vanilla DOM manipulation to Angular. I would suggest you spend some time researching how to do DOM manipulation in Angular, because manually targeting the elements and their properties is probably the least supported way to do it. Sometimes it's necessary for *really* edge cases, but by-in-large, if you find yourself doing that, you're doing something wrong.